# resize the labels of x axis in a pareto.char() - package qcc

Tags: r, resize, label, qcc

How to resize the label of x axis in a pareto.chat(), for example:

```
defect <- c(80, 27, 66, 94, 33)
names(defect) <- c("price code", "schedule date", "supplier code",
                   "contact num.", "part num.")
pareto.chart(defect, ylab = "Error frequency")
```

[image]

what I want is to make smaller the labels "contact num.", "price code", ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = rpois(10, 10)
names(x) = paste0("x", 1:length(x))
par(cex.axis = 0.4)
pareto.chart(x)
```

Comment: The solution will scale both, x and y labels. Is it possible to scale just the (longer) x labels?